# Two foreach statements with only one MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is this the only way to use two `foreach` statements with arrays going into a MySQL database?

The first one will update the `ot_hours` field, and the second `foreach` will update the `lieu_hours` field. I tried to combine both to do one query but it kept updating with wrong values.

This is what I have right now that works but is ugly.

```
foreach($_POST['overtimehours'] as $key => $value) { 
    dbQuery("UPDATE $TABLE SET ot_hours='$value', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)");
}
foreach($_POST['lieutimehours'] as $key2 => $value2) {
    dbQuery("UPDATE $TABLE SET lieu_hours='$value2', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key2 AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)");
}
```

I'm sure there's much better ways to do this. This is why I'm hoping someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance for all responses

Comment: you are asking for SQLInjection with your code

Comment: can u explain more how someone can sqlinject there?

Comment: First statement, the value of `$value` is **"0';drop database; --"**

Comment: its from a pull down menu .. not inputted value.. bt ok thanks ill be more careful

Comment: @rubberchicken Try running the following JS on your page: `var s = window.document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('src', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js');
window.document.body.appendChild(s);
jQuery('select').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(jQuery('<input />').attr('name', jQuery(this).attr('name')));
});` **Any input from the user is untrusted.**

Comment: (In case that doesn't quite work, the intention is to demonstrate how easily a drop-down list can be swapped for a free-text input. In fact, a malicious user needn't actually submit your form at all, they just need to know the right field names and build their own.)

Comment: @rubberchicken, the fastest solution is the one of the mentionned stackoverflow subject as 1st comment.

Comment: @IMSoP - I did not know that...thanks for the heads up... mysql_real_escape_string() should prevent any sqlinjection tho right?

Comment: @rubberchicken Yes, the right escape function used carefully *should* protect you. If you can get your head around prepared statements, they give you even more peace of mind (although it's still possible to make mistakes), and may also improve the performance of your code.

Comment: @rubberchicken no, it will not prevent you from all sql injections. Your database can still be dropped and injected in other ways, You must use prepared statements. It ony escapes illegal characters, but the user can still insert "legal" commands like ' or '1'='1 which can result in a very bad way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applied to your case, here is the adapted [answer of Danny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714417/1291428):

```
<?php

//first query:
$arrk = array_keys($_POST['overtimehours']);
$arrv = array_values($_POST['overtimehours']);
$id_list = implode(',', $arrk);

$whens = implode(
    "\n    ",
    array_map(
        function ($id, $value) {
            return "WHEN {$id} THEN {$value}";
        },
        $arrk,
        $arrv
    )
);

$sql1 = "
    UPDATE $TABLE
    SET ot_hours = CASE trans_num
    {$whens}
    END,
    ot_status=1, 
    ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate'
    WHERE id IN ({$id_list})
    AND uid='$contextUser' 
    AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3) 
";

//second query:
$arrk = array_keys($_POST['lieutimehours']);
$arrv = array_values($_POST['lieutimehours']);

$id_list = implode(',', $arrk);

$whens = implode(
    "\n    ",
    array_map(
        function ($id, $value) {
            return "WHEN {$id} THEN {$value}";
        },
        $arrk,
        $arrv
    )
);

$sql2 = "
    UPDATE $TABLE
    SET lieu_hours = CASE trans_num
    {$whens}
    END,
    ot_status=1, 
    ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate'
    WHERE id IN ({$id_list})
    AND uid='$contextUser' 
    AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3) 
";

//now use pdo to run sql1 and sql2

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

At least you're willing to learn new things, that's good.

- Don't assume that everything you expect to be posted is actually posted.

Use the ternary operation and the isset function to check if your posts are actually in place:

```
$overTimeHours = isset($_POST['overtimehours']) ? $_POST['overtimehours'] : false;
$lieuTimeHours = isset($_POST['lieutimehours']) ? $_POST['lieutimehours'] : false;
if($overTimeHours != false && $lieuTimeHours != false)
{
    // Proceed ; checkpoint #1
}
else
{
    // The values were not posted, do some error handling.
}
```

So at this point, inside of checkpoint #1, you would be doing this:

```
foreach($overTimeHours as $key => $value)
{ 
    dbQuery("UPDATE $TABLE SET ot_hours='$value', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)");
}
foreach($lieuTimeHours as $key2 => $value2)
{
    dbQuery("UPDATE $TABLE SET lieu_hours='$value2', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key2 AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)");
}
```

- You would probably not find it ugly to run through a single for loop if you only had one array to parse through.

Now you have two arrays (obviously), so if the minimum amount of loops for one array is one for loop, then the minimum amount of loops that you need for two arrays have to be two. The arrays are UNRELATED so you can't use one to make parsing the other one easier.

Parsing through $overTimeHours with

```
$overTimeHours as $key => $value
```

assuming that you really need the keys and the values inside of the array, is the shortest thing you can do. Same story goes for lieuTimeHours

- Your code is vonurable to SQL-injections.

Don't insert variables into your query like this:

```
SET lieu_hours='$value2'
```

A decent programmer (or a 12-year old kid) could easily enter something like this into your database:

```
yo';DROP TAbLE users;--
```

Or something similar, to delete data from your database. You must use prepared statements in order to prevent from being attacked with basic SQL-injections.

Prepared statements are available in most situations there are, but I highly recommend using either PDO or the mysqli syntax.

Here's an example of how you can create a PDO connection:

```
// Usage:   $db = connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
// Pre:     $dbHost is the database hostname, 
//          $dbName is the name of the database itself,
//          $dbUsername is the username to access the database,
//          $dbPassword is the password for the user of the database.
// Post:    $db is an PDO connection to the database, based on the input parameters.
function connectToDatabase($dbHost, $dbName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword)
{
    try
    {
         return new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=UTF-8", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    }
    catch(PDOException $PDOexception)
    {
        exit("<p>An error ocurred: Can't connect to database. </p><p>More preciesly: ". $PDOexception->getMessage(). "</p>");
    }
}
```

Now you can init the database variables:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$databaseName = 'databaseName';
$pass = '';
```

And now you can access your database via

```
$db = connectToDatabase($host, $databaseName, $user, $pass); // You can make it be a global variable if you want to access it from somewhere else.
```

Now you can create a query that accepts prepared statements:

```
$query = "UPDATE :table SET ot_hours=:ot_hours, ot_status=1, ot_submitdate=:ot_submitdate WHERE trans_num=:key AND uid=:contextUser AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3);";
```

And you can now easily prepare it, execute your variables INTO the query WITHOUT being vonurable to sql injections (The difference is really: the non-prepared queries run COMMANDS, meanwhile the prepared ones are plain STRINGS):

```
$statement = $db->prepare($query); // Prepare the query.
$success = $statement->execute(array(
    ':table' => $TABLE,
    ':ot_hours' => $ot_hours,
    ':ot_submitdate ' => $ot_submitdate ,
    ':key' => $key,
    ':contextUser' => $contextUser
)); // Here you insert the variable, by executing it 'into' the prepared query.

if($success)
{
    // Update was successful.
]
else
{
    // Update was not successful, feel free to catch an PDOException $PDOexception
}
```

Also I note that I added a ";" at the end of your script, which is not REQUORED but I feel that it's safer, to make sure to tell that your execution is finished and you don't want anything related to follow (even though It's not from you).

I hope that I answered your question/s (and hopefully way beyond that), I hope that you'll consider what I said :) Feel free to ask if there are any questions.

Also, don't hesitate to correct me if I may have said anything incorrectly meanwhile writing this answer.

Comment: Prepared statements are a good idea for this situation for another reason as well: you can prepare the statement once, before the loop, and then execute it multiple times. This allows the DBMS (MySQL in this case) to "plan" the query in advance, and will result in much better performance.

Comment: nice post, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: @Sebas Thanks, but I believe that I said that I don't think there is a better way to do this (that is, two for loops), since there are 2 unique arrays. I'll stick around to see if I'm wrong.

Comment: @IMSoP That is true, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use prepared statement. You should at least correctly encode other variables you use (`$TABLE`, ...)

```
$firstUpdate = 
    "UPDATE $TABLE 
        SET ot_hours=:value, ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' 
      WHERE trans_num=:key 
        AND uid='$contextUser' 
        AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)";

 $secondUpdate =
     "UPDATE $TABLE 
         SET lieu_hours=':value', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' 
       WHERE trans_num=:key 
         AND uid='$contextUser' 
         AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3)";

$db = PDO(...); // I assume here a connection managed by PDO

$stmt = $db->prepare($firstUpdate);
foreach($_POST['overtimehours'] as $key => $value) {
      $stmt->execute(array(":key"=>$key,":value"=>$value);
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($secondUpdate);
foreach($_POST['lieutimehours'] as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->execute(array(":key"=>$key,":value"=>$value);
}
```

Comment: A comment would be nice when downvoting..

Comment: yes i agree.. i would like to know why someone did not like your response... thank you anyways, i respect all comments.

Comment: i'm upvoting you because this is actually a case where using prepared statements would result into performances gain. But I guess doing only 1 query would be the best anyway.

Comment: Thanks for upvoting :-) Actually I overlooked the fact, that the for loops will only execute once each (Mea Culpa!) and I totally agree, that one query in this case is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion first thing you have to do is reduce the number of opening the connections with the DB like the following:

```
$query = "";
foreach($_POST['overtimehours'] as $key => $value) { 
    $query .="UPDATE $TABLE SET ot_hours='$value', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3) ; ";
}
foreach($_POST['lieutimehours'] as $key2 => $value2) {
    $query .= "UPDATE $TABLE SET lieu_hours='$value2', ot_status=1, ot_submitdate='$ot_submitdate' WHERE trans_num=$key2 AND uid='$contextUser' AND (ot_status=0 OR ot_status=1 OR ot_status=3); ";
} 
if ($query)  dbQuery($query);
```

second and it is important, like you said combine the two arrays in one try and debug your code untill you succeed .