# Cannot get a PHP update function to work

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, project

Hi I am using html and PHP to update a variable in a database table, I have made sure that the html form works correctly and have used echos to make sure the script is running through. It isnt giving me any signs of error but wont update the table. To clarify my html code is working fine as the function is working and all the right echos are coming out. Here is the code I hope someone can enlighten me as to where I am going wrong. Thank you!

```
<?php
session_start();
$healthyPig = 50;
$userNamer = $_SESSION['rememberMe'];
echo $userNamer;
$connect=(mysql_connect("localhost","lpwd10","lpwd10","lpwd10_proj"));
if (mysql_error())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect";
  }
echo "connected SON";
mysql_query($connect,"UPDATE user SET 'pigHealth' = $healthyPig WHERE userName='$userNamer'");
header('Location: pigManager.php');
echo "Complete";
mysql_close($con);



?>
```

Comment: Try `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());` to see output errors.

Comment: your SET 'pigHealth' = is incorrect at the very least.  omit the single quotes, or use backticks.  I'd suggest just changing it to SET pigHealth = $healthyPig ...

Comment: Does the user with the correct username exist in the table? And maybe you need to select the correct database with `mysql_select_db()`?

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: Let me know the url of the website once It's finished, I'd love to sql-inject it. I'm kidding, but seriously, It's sooo easy with your code, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023217/two-foreach-statements-with-only-one-mysql-query/16023628#16023628 I cba to rewrite it here.

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 2):

The value should be in quotes, not the column name

`"UPDATE user SET pigHealth = '$healthyPig' WHERE userName='$userNamer'"`

Comment: Hi, i have fixed my syntax and it still isnt working. The username is taken from a session variable and using echos I have made sure it is passed into the script. I am not worried about sql injection at the moment, it will be something that will be addressed later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the `mysql_` and `mysqli_` extensions muddled up.

Using the `mysql_` extension your `query()` statement is wrong

```
mysql_query($connect,"UPDATE user SET 'pigHealth' = $healthyPig WHERE   userName='$userNamer'");
```

Should be

```
mysql_query("UPDATE user SET 'pigHealth' = $healthyPig WHERE userName='$userNamer'", $connect);
```

> BUT you should not be using the `mysql_` extension anymore, its been deprecated for years and has been completely removed from PHP7, so any code you write using it will not run on PHP7.
>
> Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)